# Book Recommendation system using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am building a recommendation system for books. The columns in the data set are:

```
userid, location, age, Book Title, Author, Year of publication, Rating
```

For this I am thinking of the attributes as

```
location, age, year of publication
```

And the output should be book title and author
so how should i create the class

How can I categorize or classify the titles of books and authors?
What are the best algorithms for doing this? Please provide paper links also

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 5):

Read [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do) by Toby Segaran for a good chapter on how to implement recommendation systems.

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting presentation regarding a research paper recommendation system, which may be along the lines of what you are looking for. It is based on Python's [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) library, and the method seems pretty sound.

http://software-carpentry.org/v4/matrix/recommend.html

Answer (score 1):

The netflix prize solution descriptions are a good place to start for solving collaborative filtering problems:

http://www2.research.att.com/~volinsky/netflix/Bellkor2008.pdf